# drawing lines using csv file of lat/long on google earth

Tags: google-earth

I have a csv file containing lat/long like this

```
xx.xxxxx, yy.yyyyy
xx.xxxxx, yy.yyyyy
xx.xxxxx, yy.yyyyy
xx.xxxxx, yy.yyyyy
xx.xxxxx, yy.yyyyy
```

How to draw lines on google earth using this csv file?

Comment: Try this: https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148072?hl=en

Comment: Its manual drawing and it time consuming and also not accurate. I have a file from which I want to draw lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below to create a KML file for use with Google Maps or Google Earth. It assumes your CSV file is called `yourCSV.csv`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Output KML header
cat<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
<Document>
<Placemark> 
 <LineString>
  <coordinates>
EOF

# Read in CSV and append a zero altitude to each line  
sed s/$/,0.0/ yourCSV.csv 

cat<<EOF
  </coordinates>
 </LineString>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
EOF
```

Save this in a file called `CSV2KML` then do this to make it executable and run it to make a file called `mylines.kml`:

```
chmod +x CSV2KML
./CSV2KML > mylines.kml
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
<Document>
<Placemark> 
<LineString>
<coordinates>
xx.xxxxx, yy.yyyyy,0.0
xx.xxxxx, yy.yyyyy,0.0
xx.xxxxx, yy.yyyyy,0.0 
xx.xxxxx, yy.yyyyy,0.0
</coordinates>
</LineString>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

If you want the line to be red, for example, change the last part so it looks like this:

```
</coordinates>
</LineString>
<Style> 
<LineStyle>  
<color>#ff0000ff</color>
</LineStyle> 
</Style>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```